# "Two Way" Rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So, I'm trying to accomplish this:

We have a URL `/brand/new-inventory.php`. This is a physical file within our site.
What I'd like it to be is `/brand/new`. Now that was easy. All I had to add was `RewriteRule ^brand/new$ brand/new-inventory.php [L,QSA]`.

Now, what I'd like to get setup and I've been struggling with is this:

We need `/brand/new-inventory.php` when viewed by someone to redirect to `/brand/new` so we have consistent URL's and what-not.

But, when I try `RewriteRule ^brand/new-inventory.php$ brand/new [R=301,L]` Firefox starts to complain about a redirect loop that will never end.

How can I rewrite a page to respond to a different URL, and redirect the old URL to the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+brand/new-inventory\.php[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /brand/new [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^brand/new$ /brand/new-inventory.php [L,NC]
```

Difference is use of `%{THE_REQUEST}` that represents original request received by Apache from your browser. Value of this variable doesn't change with application of other rewrite rules.

Comment: What is the `\s/+` for? Why would there be a space before the request URI?

Comment: `%{THE_REQUEST}` has this content `GET /brand/new-inventory.php HTTP/1.1`