# How can I change the URL in the browser by htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change my url by htaccess from
**http://example.com/offer?search=something** to **http://example.com/offer/something**

The following htaccess works from http://example.com/offer/something but if I typing the http://example.com/offer?search=something then the url is not changing to http://example.com/offer/something.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^offer/([^/]*)$ /offer?search=$1 [L]
```

Should I use "rewritecond"? What is the correct htaccess in this case?

I try make it in Laravel framwork. I have only one htaccess and this is the content, currently:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^offer$ /offer/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^offer/([^/]*)$ /offer?search=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: unless you do a client-side redirect, e.g. `[R=301]`, mod_rewrite only changes the url internally within apache. the rewritten would never be visible to the remote user.

Comment: To clarify: If the rewrite works from `/something` to `?search=something`, then it won't work in the opposite direction. Are you asking for the rewrite code that will do the opposite?

Comment: Without any feedback, it's hard to tell.. but I suggest editing the title of your post to something that indicates a two-way redirect (i.e. it rewrites in both directions).

Comment: I don't want to two way redirect, the url with get parameters should be redirected to the pretty url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [“Two Way” Rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415348/two-way-rewrite)

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE: Full .htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# redirect URL with GET parameter to pretty URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+offer\?search=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /offer/%1? [R=301,L]

# rewrite from pretty URL to actual handle
RewriteRule ^(offer/[^/]+)/?$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

**How it prevents looping:**  `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and **it doesn't get overwritten after execution of other rewrite rules, unline `%{REQUEST_URI}` which gets overwritten after other rules**. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: @david: I have provided your full .htaccess in answer so that you can copy/paste directly.

Comment: Would be awesome to explain a little about how using `%{THE_REQUEST}` prevents infinite looping ([like you did here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415348/two-way-rewrite)). It seems that's the key.

Comment: This version redirects to http://example.com/var/www/project/webroot/laravel/public/offer/keyword instead of http://example.com/offer/keyword

Comment: @david: Also see updated code where I have added leading slash before `/offer` in 301 rule.

Comment: @anubhava: I updated it by your modifications, now It is redirecting to the correct url, but I get not-found-404 error. But the url works by the original htaccess

Comment: When you get 404 what URL does your browser show? Is it now `http://example.com/offer/something`?

Comment: Yes, it is a frontend message from apache, url is http://example.com/offer/keyword (it is now 404) but http://example.com/index.php/offer/keyword get 200. I think the index.php is missing from one rule.

Comment: Now, it works, if the last 3 lines are placed after this line: RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: You mean `# Handle Front Controller...` rule right below `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]` line

Comment: Yes, below RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to include a redirect from the url that contain a query string. I haven't tested this, but the first rule should catch the first URL and redirect it to the new format. The second rule should catch the new format and pass the correct values to the search parameter.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^offer$ /offer/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^offer/([^/]*)$ /offer?search=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I don't think you can capture query strings like that. I believe you have to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`. [Examples here](http://zenverse.net/capture-query-string-get-data-in-htaccess-rewrite/).

Comment: Yup, I forgot about that. Edited the code to reflect checking the `%{QUERY_STRING}`.

Comment: I suggest `RewriteRule ^offer$ /offer/%1? [R=301, L]`.

Comment: I tried this, the PHP error log says: "RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters"

Comment: Try removing the space between R=301, and the L. From `[R=301, L]` to `[R=301,L]`.

Comment: This will cause infinite looping. Pls test it.

Comment: Yes even with `L` flag. That's why I suggested to do testing.

Comment: The first rule will stop when it matches and redirect. The second rule will catch the redirect from the first rule and just pass the data to the server with no redirect and stop. Not sure where the loop would happen.

Comment: Repeating 3rd time **test it out** and see what it does.

Comment: If there is not space between 301 and L then it doesn't have flag error. But it doesn't try redirect, it allows to PHP to run without any redirect.

Comment: @anubhava Speaking of repeating things... Did you see the OP's last comment? He doesn't want the two-way redirect -- just rewriting from the query string to the "pretty" url. There's no way for that to infinitely loop.

Comment: OP's requirements are: **but if I typing the `http://example.com/offer?search=something` then the url is not changing to `http://example.com/offer/something`**

Comment: OP's comments are: `I don't want to two way redirect, the url with get parameters should be redirected to the pretty url.`

Comment: `url with get parameters should be redirected to the pretty url` That is exactly this answer is not doing, did you test it?

Comment: There is no need to test it as the part that causes looping is unnecessary. As I have mentioned, both answers should be edited to reflect the OP's comments. This battle is irrelevant.

Comment: Because, as I have already mentioned, and per the OP's comment, the second `RewriteRule` is not necessary.

Comment: I updated my question about content of htaccess file, maybe the other rules are causing error.

Comment: OP already has this rule `RewriteRule ^offer/([^/]*)$ /offer?search=$1 [L]` and will need a redirect rule to handle *url with get parameters should be redirected to the pretty url** requirement.

Comment: In my opinion, that was not clear. Hopefully the OP's edit will help to clarify.