# Smarty prettify url when using controllers

Tags: php, .htaccess

I found this post which matches my needs the most, I just didnt get this to work fully for my needs.
[How can I change the URL in the browser by htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306469/how-can-i-change-the-url-in-the-browser-by-htaccess)

I have url's like these:

```
mysite.de/index.php?cl=services
```

I'd love to have something like this:

```
mysite.de/services
```

What is the easiest way to do so?

Comment: When you say you can' get it to work for your needs, what are your needs? What is `cl=`, is it a page name or ID, what characters are possible in the parameter value, etc. Please _edit your post_ and try not to comment with answers when someone is asking for clarification.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed a few English issues.  I also marked up the urls by adding 4 spaces to them.  It would help others to help you faster if you posted your current effort.  What have you tried so far and what did it achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=profile&id=$1
```

Should work for :

```
www.domain.com/index.php?p=profile&id=20
```

to

```
www.domain.com/profile/20/profile-friendly-name
```

Comment: how woul it look like when i want to re re-route every call - not only related to one specific page

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example it would be

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^services$ /index.php?cl=services [L]
```

If you need multiple URLs you need multiple `RewriteRule`s. Or you could group them together (i.e. `RewriteRule ^(services|contact)$ /index.php?cl=$1`), but multiple rules is way easier to read and maintain.